# Check In on facebook wall using facebook-ios-sdk for predefined list of address

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, mapkit, checkin

I am working on an iPhone app, in which I have to enlist all nearby places and post its check in update on users facebook wall if he/she does so. As of now I made set up for Facebook SSO and I have my current latitude and longitude. I have address of all the place of my apps interest. I am stucked with two questions 1st one is how can I show nearest of them and other near by suppose like 10 of them? and the 2nd one is how can I post it on facebook wall?

Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this tutorial might help:

[Facebook checkin for iOS tutorial](http://tylerwhitedesign.com/how-to-check-in-using-the-facebook-ios-sdk-and-graph-api)

Comment: This link does not exist ... do you have any alternative link for the same topic. I ll highly appreciate your effort.